# Ubuntu 12.10 music folders to ipad

Tags: ipad

How can I move my music files from Ubuntu 12.10 to an old iPad classic that a friend gave me?

Or is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[GtkPod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home) works for adding music to iPods (confirmed with iPod Nano 4th Gen), so it might work with iPads as well.

Depending on the version of iTunes, it is possible to install it through [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347). I can confirm through experience that iTunes 8 will install, and works pretty well, under Wine 1.4, but I haven't had a chance to test syncing since my iPod is currently not working.

In my opinion, its worth a shot.

Comment: No native Ubuntu applications? I notice some files in the software center for ipad's but there are many and I don't know what they are for.

Comment: I know that gtkPod works for adding music to iPods, so it might work with an iPad as well. (added to answer)

Answer (score 0):

Banshee has a plugin (Edit -> Preferences -> Extensions), which can connect to Apple devices. I didn't try it myself, but maybe it works. You can find Banshee with this plugin in the Ubuntu packages.

Comment: I tried Banshee and was encouraged when I saw the plug in and the ipad was recognized. I tried syncing the songs and there was a progress bar but when it finished the music was not found in the ipad music section. ?? GTKPod seems to do nothing.